# HDF5 Read Dataset in Thread Error

Tags: c#, multithreading, hdf5

I write Server Application which will send extracted data from HDF5 files to many clients simultaneously

There is a code (run in separate thread):

```
var _fileID = H5F.open("C:\\Temp\\MLS-Aura_L2GP-Temperature_v03-33-c01_2012d347.he5", H5F.OpenMode.ACC_RDONLY);
H5D.open(_fileID, "/HDFEOS/SWATHS/Temperature/Data Fields/Temperature");
var space = H5D.getSpace(dataset);
var size = H5S.getSimpleExtentDims(space);
float[,] SatData = new float[size[0], size[1]];
var wrapArray = new H5Array<float>(SatData);
var dataType = H5D.getType(dataset);
H5D.read(dataset, dataType, wrapArray);
```

If I try to read HDF5 dataset in separate thread "H5D.read(dataset, dataType, wrapArray);"
with more than one thread, i have an Error: "Failed to read data to data set 5000001 with status -1"

What's the problem?

Comment: Same issue, but I have 5000000 instead of 5000001. And I only have one thread. Did you manage to resolve it eventually?

Comment: In my case the issue was that reader and writer were different application and their definitions of compound type were slightly different: writer had a UTF8 string, while reader had a regular string. Managed to fix it by updating the contract.

Comment: And I am getting 5000002 error. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

HDF5 library should be compiled with threadsafe mode in order to be used in a multi threaded environment.

```
./configure --enable-threadsafe ...
```

Yet, this configuration assure only threadsafety, but not thread parallelism. In fact current HDF5 version 1.10 implements threadsafe mode with a very simple mutex protection, so every HDF5 operation called by multiple thread is actually serialized.